# Creating a suppressConditions function to suppress everything

Tags: r, error-handling

I have been meaning to write a suppressConditions function to suppress every condition such as error, warning and message. For that purpose I have reviewed the source code of `suppressMessage` and `suppressWarning` functions and couldn't figure out why the `classes` argument only contains one condition and we cannot use a general function for both purposes:

I would like to know why this code works in muffling either message or warning condition, whereas the following code doesn't:

```
suppressConditions <- function(expr, condition = "message") {
  withCallingHandlers(
    condition = function(cons) {
      if(inherits(cons, condition)) {
        rlang::cnd_muffle(cons)
      }
    },
    expr
  )
}

suppressConditions(message("hello!")) # It works

suppressConditions <- function(expr, conditions = c("message", "warning")) {
  withCallingHandlers(
    conditions = function(cons) {
      if(inherits(cons, conditions)) {
        rlang::cnd_muffle(cons)
      }
    },
    expr
  )
}

> suppressConditions(message("hello!")) # It doesn't work
hello!
```

So in the end I would like to know how I can add error condition to this function so that it suppress all three conditions.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to pass the different condition handlers as separate params to `withCallingHandlers`. The easiest way to do that is to build a list of parameters and then use `do.call` to actually call the function.

This should work

```
suppressConditions <- function(expr, conditions = c("message", "warning")) {
  fn <- function(cons) {
    if(inherits(cons, conditions)) {
      rlang::cnd_muffle(cons)
    }
  }
  conds <- setNames(rep(list(fn), length(conditions)), conditions)
  invisible(do.call("withCallingHandlers", c(list(substitute(expr)), conds)))
}

suppressConditions(message("hello!"))
suppressConditions(warning("oops!"))
```

We make a list that repeats the handling functions for each condition type and then name that the condition name. We combine that with `expr` in a list, wrapping it in `substitute()` so we don't evaluate it prematurely. This will call the function with the correct parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much @MrFlick, it was a very informative and beautiful answer that teaches me a lot of functions with various applications all at once. I've covered 1/3 of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R and every day there are so many great things to learn. I only have one question in your answer we don't define the `env` argument in `substitute`, right?

Comment: The `env` parameter will default to the current environment which is where `expr` is defined. Since that's what we don't I don't see any reason to explicitly set it.